# Android App to launch all the installed apps on the device

Tags: android, launch

I am working on a test app that will launch every app on the device one after the other continuously.The app is mainly intended for UI stability testing through context switch.I am new to Android and trying to figure out things along the way.I will deeply appreciate any suggestions

This is what my app is suppose to be doing:-

1. Query the device and get a list of all the apps on the device
   including system apps
2. Now launch each app one after the other until all the apps on the device are launched
3. Once it completes going through the list once,it starts over again from first app in the list

   Lets call my app Launcher_app and say there are 5 apps A,B,C,D,E  on the device.Launcher app will launch A,then B,C,D,E in that order    and starts again by launching A.This is will continue until the user    manually exist launcher app

I tried to implement the app,but I have a few questions on how android system will allow such a context switch.

This is a code snippet that auto launches each app

ublic Runnable AutoLaunch = new Runnable() {

```
public void run()
{

   while(AppIndex < mAppsList.getCount())
   {


       //get the app name using index AppIndex
       //launch app using the appname
      App app = (App) mAppsList.getItemAtPosition(AppIndex);
     Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.getPackageName());
       try 
          {
             if (i != null) 
             {
                startActivity(i);

             } 
             else 
             {
                i = new Intent(app.getPackageName());
                startActivity(i);

             }
             for(int j=0;j<2000;j++)
                 for(int k=0;k<10000;k++)
                     continue;
             finish();

          } 
          catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) 
          {
             //Toast.makeText(ListInstalledApps.this, "Error launching app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

    if(AppIndex == mAppsList.getCount()-1)
          AppIndex = 0;
      else                
          AppIndex++;

   }
```

This is my undertsanding:-

Launcher app will be in foreground (FG) at the very beginning.
then app A comes to Forground n Launcher_app will go into Background(BG).
Now app B comes to FG and app A goes into BG along with Launcher app.
Continuing this way there comes a time when app E is in FG and the rest of the apps including Launcher app are in BG.

When i try to run the app with above implementation ,I see the apps getting launched but the app order is randopm,also,I dont see very app ont he device getting launched,probably it's happening too fast....not sure.I didnt' want to proceed until I knwo I'm on the right track

In this situation for the next iteration ,will Launhcer app resume app A,B,C,D ,E in that order or will it restart each app ?Also will Launcher app get killed if the system needs memory in an actual scenario where there are close to 50 apps ont he device running in BG.Or will the system keep my app alive since this is the main app that's launchign all the other apps.

Kindly help me understand how it works,as I really wnat to know is such an app is even feasible? What's the best way to address the above issues.Will be grateful for any kind  of pointers /suggestions.

Thanks
mini

Answer (score 2):

What is this:

```
for(int j=0;j<2000;j++)
    for(int k=0;k<10000;k++)
        continue;
```

If you're just trying to introduce a delay, you could simply sleep for a while or use something like [`postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to space out the calls.

I would agree with your guess that the apps are simply launching too fast. You're essentially launching all of them all at once, so you'll see what appears to be a random order (due to differing startup times) and some that don't even have time to display their UI before another one grabs focus.

Fix your delaying code and most of this should be much better.

Comment: thank you.I will try using postDelayed,but PostDelayed is to run an executable after some delay right?I am already doing this before i start autolaunch: mHandler = new Handler(); mHandler.postDelayed(AutoLaunch,5000);The delay above(with the for loops ) is intended so that the launched app can atleast load properly.Could you tell me how I can insert delay between the apps that are launched for the user to differentiate the variosu apps that are launched on the device screen

Comment: Works after I replace the for loop with thread.sleep(4000) for the delay